# Java delete ZipEntry

Tags: java, jar, zip

at first I have to say, I already looked in the internet / stackoverflow, but the solutions didnt work for me, because I'm new to Java and dont understand too complex code.

I want to delete an Entry (Folder) inside a *.jar File.
Is there a simple way to handle this, like:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("path\\File.jar\\Folder");
entry.delete();
```

If its not possible to delete a ZipEntry, how can I rename a Folder inside a *.jar File?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there's no method for deleting or renaming a ZipEntry inside a ZipFile. You'll have to create a new ZipFile, copy the ZipEntries ommiting the one you want to delete.

Comment: And there is also no way to RENAME a file inside a ZipFile? This would be an alternative solution for my problem??

Comment: I'm afraid not @user3430746

Comment: I found a way to delete a ZipEntry with Zip4j Library (http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/).
Unfortunately it's not possible to delete a whole folder with it (or at leasts I didnt find a way to), but its enough for my needs.

But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to achieve this using Java 7: Zip FileSystem

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
env.put("create", "false");

URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:///C:/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip"); // Zip file path

try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
    Files.delete(zipfs.getPath("/SomeTextFile.txt")); // File inside zip to delete
}
```